# How do I get all the stats about a specified pid? E.g. how long it ran? max/min/avg usage of cpu, memory, disk and network?

Tags: process

Here is a tiny C++ app

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    std::cout << "pid = " << getpid() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

which just simply prints a string and the pid of the app.

How do I get all the stats about this pid? E.g. how long did it run? What is the maximum, minimum and average usage of cpu, memory, disk and network?

Note: When I get the pid, the app is finished, which means `/proc/PID/` doesn't work.

```
$ ./a.out
Hello World
pid = 19691                   
$ cd /proc/19691
-bash: cd: /proc/19691: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if the process whose resource usage should be measured was a child of the process doing the measuring: you need another program which will run your `a.out`, wait for it, and then call [`getrusage`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html):

```
struct rusage rusage;
getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &rusage);
```

This will fill the `rusage` structure with aggregate resource usage for all the caller’s children which have terminated and been waited for.

On Linux you can use [the `wait4` system call](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) to combine waiting and a child-specific `getrusage` call.